# Привязка footer'a к нижней части экрана android

Tags: android, listview

При небольшом количестве элементов в списке возникает проблема с пустым  местом на экране. Нужно что бы footer был прижат к нижней части экрана, причем блок обведенный красным должен быть как элемент списка и быть как бы последним элементом в этом списке. Если с помощью listView это реализовать невозможно, возможно есть другие варианты?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorWhite"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".activities.MainActivity">


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/appBarLayout"
    android:background="@drawable/header_button_shape_baground"
    android:gravity="center">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnStart"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_start_background"
        android:text="НАЧАТЬ"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="5dp"
    android:focusable="false" />


 </LinearLayout>
```

list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="@color/colorWhite"
>


<!-- Progress Bar -->

<com.github.lzyzsd.circleprogress.CircleProgress
    android:id="@+id/donut_progress"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="20.5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="20.5dp"
    custom:donut_progress="70"
    custom:circle_text_size="14sp"
    custom:circle_finished_color="@color/colorGreen"
    custom:circle_unfinished_color="@color/colorBackgroundDarckGrey"
    />

<!-- Title of package-->
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/titleDescription"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/donut_progress"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/donut_progress"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/buyCase"
    android:paddingTop="20.5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="20.5dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Rihanna Love the way"
        android:textColor="@color/colorFontBlue"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:typeface="sans"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:text="Just gona stand there and ..."
        android:textColor="#535353"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        />

</LinearLayout>


<!--Buy and about-->

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/buyCase"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="20.5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="20.5dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/titleDescription">

    <!-- Buy button -->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnBuy"
        android:layout_width="62.5dp"
        android:layout_height="26dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_board_baground"
        android:text="4.99 $"
        android:textColor="@color/colorFontBlue"

        />

    <!-- Short description about package -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/count"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
        android:text="230 words"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        />

</LinearLayout>

<!--  SHADOWS -->

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/shadowLayoutBottom"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="5dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@drawable/shadow_bottom"
    android:orientation="horizontal" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutTop"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1.7dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/shadow_top"
    android:orientation="vertical" />




 </RelativeLayout>
```

footer.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorWhite"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".activities.MainActivity">

<!-- SING UP FACEBOOK -->

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/singUpFacebook"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"

    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/titleDescription"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/facebookImageView"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="20.5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="20.5dp">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewTitleFacebook"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Привязаться к аккаунту Facebook"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewDescriptionFacebook"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Что бы сохранить свои покупки и пройденные слова в случае смены телефона"
            android:textColor="#535353"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="normal" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/facebookImageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:src="@drawable/facebook"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:paddingTop="20.5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="20.5dp" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/shadowLayoutBottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/shadow_bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutTop"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1.7dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shadow_top"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</RelativeLayout>


<!-- INVATE FRIENDS ON FACEBOOK -->


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutInviteFacebook"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/singUpFacebook"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/item_shape_baground"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/shadowTop"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1.7dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/shadow_top"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/inviteFriendsTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Пригласите 10 друзей и получите блок слов о партнерстве в бизнесе"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"

        android:paddingTop="22dp"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonInviteFriends"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/inviteFriendsTextView"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_board_baground"
        android:text="Пригласить друей"
        android:textColor="@color/colorFontBlue"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginBottom="22dp"
        />

</LinearLayout>



<!-- FOOTER  -->

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/footerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayoutInviteFacebook"
    android:background="@color/colorBackgroundGrey"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/shadow_top"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1.7dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/shadow_top"
        android:orientation="vertical" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="2dp"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewFooterTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Privacy policy | Support"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/colorFontBlue"
            android:textSize="13dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewDescriptionFooter"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textViewFooterTitle"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:text="2015"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textSize="13dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Main.java

```
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    buttonStart = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnStart);
    mList = (ArrayList<Paket>)MockData.getListItems();


    recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new BottomStickyLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.footer_activity_main));


    recyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(mList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);
}
```

adapter.java

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.PaketViewHolder>{

List<Paket> list;

public RecyclerViewAdapter(List<Paket> list) {
    this.list = list;
}

@Override
public PaketViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_list_main, parent, false);
    PaketViewHolder pvh = new PaketViewHolder(v);
    return pvh;

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(PaketViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.title.setText(list.get(position).getmTitle());
    holder.description.setText(list.get(position).getmDescription());
    holder.count.setText(list.get(position).getmWordCount());
    holder.button.setText(list.get(position).getmPrice());

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
}


public static class PaketViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView title;
    TextView  description;
    TextView count ;
    CircleProgress progress;
    Button button;

    PaketViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        title = ((TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title));

        description = ((TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.description));

        count = ((TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.count));

        progress = (CircleProgress)itemView.findViewById(R.id.donut_progress);

        button = (Button)itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnBuy);
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Попробуйте проставить корневому элементу высоту полную: `android:layout_height="match_parent"`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб а корневому элементу - чего именно? если activity_main.xml уже пробовал - не помогло, сейчас исправлю в вопросе, что бы не сбивать с толку

Comment: Ну, того, коий список содержит...  И отформатируйте код в вопросе, кажется там часть его не отображается.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб код  отформатировал,  вариант с match_parent попробовал - не получилось.

Comment: То, что обведено красным должно быть как на скрине при коротком списке, а то, что ниже обведённого должно отображаться всегда, то последнее надо вынести из списка и просто поместить ниже его. А вообще пока не ясно что именно вы хотите и зачем лишний код в вопросе. Попробуйте однозначно сформудировать что вам надо и уберите неотносящийся к вопросу код. Имеется в виду ява-код активити - ибо зачем он в вопросе?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб То что обведено красным - тоже часть футера и элементом списка - не является, но должно находиться в конце списка,  а если вынести нижнюю  часть footer'а и поместить в низ экрана, то как тогда быть с прокруткой списка, когда там будет больше элементов, он ведь будет отображаться постоянно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С ListView такое и правда не реализовать, я похожую задачу реализовал следующим образом. Список на RecyclerView, 3 типа элементов: собственно сами элементы списка, футор (далее footor1) который должен быть в конце списка, футор (далее footor2) который должен быть в конце списка если список большой и в самом низу окна если список маленький. Реализацию адаптера для RecyclerView описывать тут не буду ибо тут всё стандартно и описаний как это делается в интернетах уже более чем достаточно. А вот что бы footor2 прилипал к низу экрана я сделал вот такой LayoutManager для RecyclerView:

```
public class BottomStickyLayoutManager extends LinearLayoutManager {
    private final int bottomViewId;

    public BottomStickyLayoutManager(Context context, int bottomViewId) {
        super(context);
        this.bottomViewId = bottomViewId;
    }

    @Override
    public void layoutDecorated(View child, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        if (child.getId() == bottomViewId && bottom < getHeight()) {
            top += getHeight() - bottom;
            bottom = getHeight();
        }
        super.layoutDecorated(child, left, top, right, bottom);
    }
}
```

Использовать его теперь нужно при инициализации RecyclerView вот так `recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new BottomStickyLayoutManager(context, R.id.footer2));`

Comment: попробывал сделать согласно вашему ответу, но что то не получается, footer вообще не отображается. Возможно я где то напартачил. Щас добавлю код в вопрос. И еще, я правильно понял, что кусок footer'а который должен быть прикреплен к списку, надо добавлять в адаптере? если да то как  имеено добавить его в конец списка?

Comment: Правильно, добавлять как элемент другого типа, с отдельным классом ViewHolder'a, вот пример http://stackoverflow.com/a/26245463/2893248

Answer (score 0):

Боюсь, стандартными средствами такое не реализовать. Вам придётся вручную измерять сумму высот всех элементов, сравнивать их с высотой экрана и, в зависимости от этого назначать высоту последнему элементу так, чтобы он заполнял всю оставшуюся высоту экрана и сместить его внутренние элементы вниз

Comment: А если использовать что то вместо ListView , на там RecycleView? И если нет то как можно реализовать тот вариант о котором вы говорите?

Comment: @KirillStoianov, `RecyclerView` тоже не предоставляет подобного функционала. Ну... Вот, например, другая идея: поместите под список разметку футера, списку задайте прозрачный фон, и, измерив высоту футера, добавьте элемент с такой высотой в качестве последнего эл-та списка. Будет не совсем как надо, но проще и довольно интересно.

Comment: я так понимаю ваш вариант, чем то похож на вариант из ответа ниже, но применим к listView  и требует меньше кода, с RecyclerView у меня что то  пока не получается, возможно все таки прийдется прибегнуть к вашему варианту, можно поподробней как это сделать, я если честно не до конца понял!

Comment: @KirillStoianov, замените лист вью на релатив. В него поместите футер с гравити боттом а следом листвью. Итого один релатив с двумя детьми..

Answer (score 0):

Как раз делал как то, BehaviorSubject из RxJava2, можете заменить чем нибудь своим если не пользуетесь

```
public class StickyFooterOffseter {
private final View stickyFooter;
private final RecyclerView recyclerView;
private final LinearLayoutManager layoutManager;
private BehaviorSubject<Integer> behaviorSubject = BehaviorSubject.create();

StickyFooterOffseter(View stickyFooter, RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    this.stickyFooter = stickyFooter;
    this.recyclerView = recyclerView;
    layoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager();

    stickyFooter.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new View.OnLayoutChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {
            if (stickyFooter.getMeasuredHeight() != 0) {
                behaviorSubject.onNext(stickyFooter.getMeasuredHeight());
                stickyFooter.removeOnLayoutChangeListener(this);
            }
        }
    });
}

void offsetStickyFooter() {
    behaviorSubject.subscribe(stickyFooterHeight -> {
        View firstView = recyclerView.getChildAt(0);
        if (firstView == null) {
            return;
        }
        if (isMoreThanScreenHeight(stickyFooterHeight)) {
            recyclerView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, stickyFooterHeight);
        } else {
            final int translateOffset = recyclerView.getChildAt(layoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition()).getBottom() - (stickyFooter.getTop() - recyclerView.getTop());
            stickyFooter.setTranslationY(translateOffset);
        }
    });
}

private boolean isMoreThanScreenHeight(int stickyFooterHeight) {
    final View view = recyclerView.getChildAt(layoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition());
    final int offset = recyclerView.getBottom() - view.getBottom();
    return stickyFooterHeight > offset || view.getBottom() + view.getMeasuredHeight() > recyclerView.getBottom();
}
```

}